# Tesseract installation

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

i have already tried to change the cmd path like this.

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR"

still hasnt work and i get this error C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\  is not installed or it's not in your PATH

and i did put it in my environment variables.

path = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/dataset/202301__/IMG_8682.JPG'

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR"

print(pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(path)))

Comment: Perhaps it should be `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"`

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, unfortunately it still doesn’t work, also the tessreact in my computer is without the exe, tho I tried with both…